# Google DoubleClickStudio - video source file

Tags: safari, webm, google-web-designer

After creating a creative banner with an mp4 video in Google Web Designer and then upload that creative to DoubleClick the source file has changed from mp4 to webm. The issue here is that webm in Safari is pixelated and the creative/ad is not shown properly, while on other browsers its ok. Is there a setting in DoubleClickStudio to prevent it from transcoding the mp4 video and use the default mp4 instead ?

...1630672923/mv/u/mvi/1/pl/24/file/file.webm

Comment: We are unable to reproduce this issue. Can you please provide the source file (not the published file) so we can take a look at it? Please upload the file to a file share server such as Google Drive, and share the URL with us at gwd-support@google.com. Thanks,
San
Google Web Designer team

Comment: Email sent. Thanks for helping on this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.